# How do I render table from web rather than this data table?

Tags: datatable, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server

I have a too big table stored in drop box via this link https://www.dropbox.com/s/k94brqtrp5thch3/005.txt?dl=0; I need to access to this table in a way the below code shows Iris data. I mean how I can read my big .txt file instead of Iris in this code please?

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(

              fluidRow(
              tabBox(width = 12, height = NULL,

                tabPanel("Data", value=2,

                         fluidRow(

                           column(width = 4,  box(title = "Iris", width = NULL, solidHeader = FALSE, dataTableOutput("dat1")))
                )
              )
    )
  )))

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$dat1 <- renderDataTable({datatable(iris)})


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You want to read your file in shiny directly from dropbox without having it in your local files ?

Comment: I want to read my file from web because it's too big to be read directly in ui and server. My ultimate goal is deploying a shiny app that is why I should address my file in both ui and server if not I can simply read my file in r as a table and assign that to a variable. Any suggestion  please?

Comment: If you don't need the entire file at a time you can use 
`con <- url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/k94brqtrp5thch3/005.txt?raw=1") ;
open(con, "r")`
in global.R and 
`datatable(read.table(con, nrows = 10))`
 in server.R. But if you need the complete file the shiny app won't load it (or at least my computer can't)

Comment: Unfortunately I need all of my file